# How to dispose a resource shared between UI thread and background thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, user-interface

Lets start with a UI thread (WPF, WinForms is fine too), and the UI thread creates a background thread to do somework (Threadpool) and when completed the background thread updates  the UI (using dispatcher). The UI thread shares a resouce with background thread and it needs to be disposed of when background thread completes its process.

What is the best way to achieve this, do we dispose the resouce from background thread itself when it finishes its job? If so we cannot use the resouce from UI thread after creating the thread as we don't know when the background thread completes and vice versa. (And no async/await features are avaiable here). As we are dealing with UI thread here, need to keep the GUI active all time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My preference is for one thread to "own" the resource and manage it.  If the UI thread owns it then it can "loan" the resource to the background thread but the UI thread is still responsible for disposing of it.  This way the UI thread can use the resource and knows whether it's disposed or not.

If possible it's better for the background worker to "own" the resource so that it can dispose it but it sounds like that is not possible in your situation.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a ref counter for the resource. Since you know that 2 threads are using the resource, start the counter with a value of 2.

Whenever a thread is finished with the resource, it must decrease the ref count. When the ref count reaches 0, the resource can be disposed. Since you are using threads, you need to synchronize this with locks. Some pseudo code:

```
int myResourceRefCount = 2;
object syncLockObject = new Object();

void DecreaseRefCountForMyResource() {
    lock(syncLockObject) {
       --myResourceRefCount;
       if(myResourceRefCount == 0)
           DisposeMyResource();
    }
}
```